# Git rev-list: exclude commits already included in a merge

Tags: git, git-rev-list

I have a repository with a master branch that has frequent merges from different defect branches, like in the picture below (defect1 is the name of the defect branch):

[image]

I would like to retrieve a list of all the commits of the master branch, from the one previous to commit A up until the head (in this case, E). This list will be used to revert all the commits due to a specific use case of my project.

I've been gathering this list by using `git rev-list`:

`git rev-list "${commitA}~1"..origin/master`

The problem is that when I do that, I get commits X and Y in the mix, while commit D already includes the changes of both commits X and Y. I can revert commit D with `git revert -m 1`. When I try to revert X and Y I get an error, since the commits are not in the master tree. I would like to retrieve A~1, A, B, C, D and E only. I could easily do something like:

`git rev-list "${commitA}~1"..origin/master ^defect1`

**but there can be multiple defect branches with different names and it's impossible to know their names in advance.**

Are there other options within git-rev-list that can enable this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
git rev-list master --first-parent
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.